# clear command in my mac os terminal gives the following error

Tags: macos, unix

dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libncursesw.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/bin/clear
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap

---

This is what my `bash_login` looks like:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH" 
export PATH="/usr/local/apache-maven-2.2.1/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="~/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Home/bin:$PATH"

export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
export MANPATH=/opt/local/share/man:$MANPATH
```

Comment: Not programming related, you will get a better response on http://www.superuser.com

Comment: I think this counts as a programming-related question. Only a programmer could damage their installation of Mac OS at such a low level, and this is beyond normal usage or normal powerusers.

Answer (score 2):

Let me guess... you put /opt/local/bin in front of /usr/bin, /bin, and /sbin or you probably set DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH and pointed it to /opt/local/lib, didn't  you? That's a really bad idea. You should always put the system executables before the ones provided by MacPorts in your path. In addition, you should never set DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, instead use DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to recompile your MacPorts stuff.

```
$ port selfupdate
```